Problems with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 8.0.3 401 unauthorised in .NET 8 ASP.NET Core
I am getting error while using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 8.0.3. Previously we were at .Net 6 we upgraded to .Net 8 and upgraded the nuget packages after that I facing this error. While its working fine with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 7.0.17.
Error:
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2024 13:48:59 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"
  Content-Length: 0
}}

I can successfully get the token but its not authorizing it.
Below code is used to Generate the token for JWT
.
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult getToken(TokenCredential _tokenCred)
    {
        IActionResult result = null;
        try
        {
            if (_tokenCred.Key.Equals(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]) && _tokenCred.Secret.Equals(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"]))
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())
                };

                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:JwtKey"]));
                var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                   _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                   _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                   claims,
                   expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Int16.Parse(_configuration["Jwt:expiresInMinutes"])),
                   signingCredentials: signIn);

                string _token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
                result = Ok(_token);
            }
            else
            {
                result = Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }



If you added minimal reproducible example, it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage. Besides, could you share the .csproj file?

@QingGuo Updated the description please have a look.

Try to use SecurityTokenDescriptor Class to create a security token,

Contains some information which used to create a security token.

Have a try like:
 var claims = new[]
                {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())
                };
 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:JwtKey"]));
 var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
 var tokenDescriptor1 = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
    Issuer =  _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Int16.Parse(_configuration["Jwt:expiresInMinutes"])),
    SigningCredentials= signIn };

 var tokenObject1 = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateToken(tokenDescriptor1);
 string _token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenObject1);

